# How to specify directory when use "gcc -c" to generate *.o files?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

The command "gcc -c" will generate *.o files to current directory.

But I want to put the *.o files to a specified directory without pollute current folder.

What should I do ?

Comment: `gcc -o obj/file1.o -c file1.c`

Comment: So that we don't have to explain everything from scratch, show us the makefile you've already got.